# Where $(x,y,z)$ will a spaceship be in a next second?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, time-evolution

Developing a physics-based video game in Unity.

Given a spaceship position, velocity vector, mass, and force vector currently applied to the ship body, I would like to calculate where it will be in the next second and a second after that, and so on.
To elaborate: The direction of a ship’s movement is changed over time by the force applied to the ship hull. This force can be applied from any angle. If from the left side, the ship is going to change direction to the right, if from the front, the ship is going to slow down, and so on.

I need a formula to calculate the ship’s projected position for every n next seconds (given the input data does not change).

Comment: *the input data does not change* So the force on the spaceship is *constant*?

Comment: Yes, at the time/frame of the calculation the force is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a spaceship position, velocity vector, weight, and force vector currently applied to the ship body, I would like to calculate where it will be in the next second and a second after that, and so on.

By "weight" I will assume you mean "mass." If this is not the case, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Anyways, assuming the mass of the space ship is fixed, and assuming the spaceship can be treated as a point, the velocity at time $t_0+\Delta t$ (where, $\Delta t$ is, say, one second) can be determined by:
$$
\vec v(t_0+\Delta t) = \vec v(t_0) + \frac{1}{m}\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t}\vec F(t)dt\;.\tag{1}
$$

The position at $t_0+\Delta t$ can be determined by:
$$
\vec x(t_0+\Delta t) = \vec x(t_0) +\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t}\left(\vec v(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t\frac{1}{m}\vec F(t')dt'\right)dt\;.\tag{2}
$$

If the force is constant ($\vec F(t) = \vec F_0$) over the entire time period $\Delta t$ then Eq. (1) becomes:
$$
\vec v(t_0+\Delta t) = \vec v(t_0) + \frac{1}{m}\vec F_0\Delta t\;.\tag{1'}
$$
and Eq. (2) becomes:
$$
\vec x(t_0+\Delta t) = \vec x(t_0) +\vec v(t_0)\Delta t + \vec F_0\frac{\Delta t^2}{2m}\tag{2'}
$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant mass. Thx

Comment: Have just implemented this(the last Eq.) in the game and it works like a charm. Thank you. Given spaceship engines usage Player can now see where he will be in the future and he can adjust engine power accordingly.

Comment: Nice. Glad it helped.